# Render partial view on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

so I've tried everything, but I simply can not return a small partial view and place it in div element.
This is my parent view

```
<button id="doctors">Doktori</button>
<button id="apointments"> Pregledi</button>

 <div id="someDiv">
 </div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("doctors").onclick = function () { myFunction() };
    function myFunction() {

        $("#someDiv").load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("doctorsview", "HomeController")) ")
    }
</script>
```

I put some alert("message") before .load() function, and it shows a message, but then I put it after .load(), it doesn't show it.
I've tried with and without html.raw(). 
This is my controller action

```
public ActionResult doctorsview()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/_Doktor.cshtml", new Doktor());        
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you don't have to pass complete name of `HomeController`, In `Url.Action()` we have to pass prefix of Controller name, when we create controller we have to add a postfix of `Controller` in mvc and when we use it in helpers we have to just pass Controller name without `Controller` postfix:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
public ActionResult doctorsview()
{
  return PartialView("~/Views/_Doktor.cshtml", new Doktor());        
}

}
```

Do like this:

```
$("#someDiv").load('@Url.Action("doctorsview","Home")');
```

and you should be placing it in respective Views directory of Controller, which is in this case **Views -> Home**

Comment: I'm dealing with this for couple of hours. Thanks a lot!